# IOS: How to add dynamic elements to Setup page

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic, swift5

I want to add elements to my signup sheet dynamically via buttons.  For example, in my picture, I have an "Add another Day" button.  When that button is clicked I want to have the "Add another Day" button pushed down a little and another day field added to the setup page.

How would I go about doing this?

My current thinking is that I make stack views for Day, Exercise, and Workout and then the buttons append another stack view when pressed. But this leads me to have a few questions:

1. To do this, would I need to make a new class for each stack view?
2. Would I put the Buttons within those classes or within the overarching Program Setup ViewController?
3. If I implement it this way should I get rid of my storyboard altogether and just implement all of these fields programmatically?

This is my first swift/IOS app and I couldn't really find any good leads for this topic so any and all help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best way to present dynamic data is to use a [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview) or [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview).

When using a UITableView or UICollectionView you would abstract your view into a model which than will be used as the datasource of your tableview or collectionview.

Some tutorials to help you start:

- https://blog.usejournal.com/easy-tableview-setup-tutorial-swift-4-ad48ec4cbd45
- https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/add-rows-table-view-ios-tutorial-ios12
- https://medium.com/@stasost/ios-how-to-build-a-table-view-with-multiple-cell-types-2df91a206429